Troubleshooting Grafana and Prometheus Loading Issue After Nginx Reverse Proxy Configuration
I've set up Grafana and Prometheus on Ubuntu using Docker, with Grafana running on port 3000 and Prometheus on port 9090. Initially, they were accessible via HTTP using IP addresses and ports. To enhance security, I configured Nginx to serve as a reverse proxy. While the URLs are now secured, Grafana and Prometheus are not loading on these secured URLs. Assistance in troubleshooting this issue would be appreciated.
I used this command to run it on docker:
sudo docker run -d --user 998:998 --net=host -v /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v /data/prometheus:/data/prometheus prom/prometheus --config.file="/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml" --storage.tsdb.path="/data/prometheus"
And below is my nginx defualt file content:
`server {
server_name www.mydomain.com;
root /var/www/html;
#server_tokens off;   
index index.html index.htm;        
location / {         
    # First attempt to server request as file, then         
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.          
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;      
}

location /prometheus {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
location /grafana {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location /node_exporter {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9100;
}

# Access and error logs
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

}`

That's because each container has own localhost (usually).
